# print arguments on function invocation

Tags: python

Wondering what the easiest way is to get debug prints.

I am looking though some code and there is some functions that use a lot of generic text arguments as inputs. So I am looking for an easy way to print the line without having to modify it to avoid getting typos or errors in there

simple example, a line in the code

```
someFunction('%s_someString', variable, 
   '%s_moreStrings' %someOtherString, someMoreString, someObject)
```

So instead of checking

```
print 'someFunction('%s_someString', %s, '%s_moreStrings', 'someObject')  %
               (someOtherString, variable, someMoreString)
```

I am looking for a way to just print exactly that. I tried to do something like writing a function that would print a string and eval it, but this does not work the way I intend

```
someFunction('someOtherString_someString', variable,  
             'someMoreString_moreStrings', someObject)
```

Is there a way to do that

Comment: To clarify, you want `x = 1; y=2; z = f(x, y)` to print `f(1, 2)`, and  set `z`?

Comment: I would already be happy with having it print f(1, 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
from functools import wraps

def prints_invocation(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args):
        print "%s(%s)" % (f.__name__, ', '.join(repr(a) for a in args))
        return f(*args)
    return wrapped
```

```
>>> @prints_invocation
... def add(x, y):
...     return x + y
>>> add(1, 2)
add(1, 2)
3
```

It would be fairly trivial to extend this to print `kwargs` and return values

Comment: thanks Eric, looks like what I was looking for. Will have a look at those wraps

Comment: `@wraps(f)` is not essential for the functionality here - it's just good practice

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using decorators?

```
def DebugDecorator(func)

    def log(*args, **kw):
        print "{0}({1}".format(func.__name__, *args)
        return func(*args, **kw)


@DebugDecorator
def someFunction():
    code
```

edit: i was too slow :)

Comment: thanks le_vine, not familiar with decorators. something new to look into